# Primefaces update fails after removing component in a model

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, jstl

My goal is to create a panel where I can drag and drop elements of two different types: button and textfield. All of the elements are stored in a TreeMap and are iterated over with JSTL `<c:forEach>` tag. I can add extra components and remove the most recently selected ones thorough dedicated p:commandXxx fields outside of the viewPanel. Once draggable components are in the viewPanel, I can drag and drop them. Through javascript, I'm appending top and left coordinates of a particular component before the drop action to update component's location is invoked. The delete commandButton should remove the selected element from the list and trigger the update of the viewPanel.

Problem: Deleting any component except the most recently added fails to update the viewPanel resulting in the following exception:

> *Severe:   Error Rendering View[/developer/testDr.xhtml]
>   org.primefaces.expression.ComponentNotFoundException: Cannot find >component for expression "button-" referenced from "defStep-10:j_idt13".*.

It appears that in render time draggable's *for* attribute evaluates #{child.idstepNode} to null. Does anyone know why this happens, or how to circumvent this?

Interestingly, when Delete button is clicked again or the whole page is refreshed, viewPanel renders without a hitch.

```
        <h:form id="viewPanel" class="default-step droppable" style="width:500px;height:500px;background:green;">

                <p:droppable for="viewPanel" tolerance="touch" activeStyleClass="ui-state-highlight" > 
                    <p:ajax listener="#{stepUtility.onDrop}" update="viewPanel" />
                </p:droppable>

        <c:forEach items="${stepUtility.stepNodesMap}" var="child">




                <c:if test="${child.value.elementType == 'BUTTON'}">
                    <p:outputLabel id="button-${child.value.idstepNode}" style="top:${child.value.top};left:${child.value.left};
background-color: beige;position:absolute;" value="button ${child.value.elementValue}"/>
                    <p:draggable for="button-${child.value.idstepNode}"/>
                </c:if>

                <c:if test="${child.value.elementType == 'TEXT'}">
                    <p:outputLabel id="text-${child.value.idstepNode}" style="top:${child.value.top};left:${child.value.left};
background-color: beige;position:absolute;" value="text ${child.value.elementValue}"/>

                    <p:draggable for="text-${child.value.idstepNode}"  />
                </c:if>


        </c:forEach>

        </h:form>

    //...
    <p:commandButton value="Delete" actionListener="#{stepUtility.removeStepNode()}" 
             update=":viewPanel"/>
```

stepUtility bean

```
@Named(value = "stepUtility")
@SessionScoped
public class StepUtility implements Serializable {

    private Integer selecteNode;
    public void setSelectedElement(Integer idstepNode) //'StepNode')
    {
        selecteNode=idstepNode;
    }

    public void addNewComp(String typeNode)
    {
        if(stepNodesMap == null)
            stepNodesMap = new TreeMap<>();

        StepNodeSimple snode = new StepNodeSimple();
        Integer id = 0;
        if(stepNodesMap.size()>0)
        {
            Integer lastNodeId = ((StepNodeSimple) stepNodesMap.lastEntry().getValue()).idstepNode;
            id = lastNodeId+1;
        }
        snode.idstepNode = id;
        snode.elementType = typeNode;
        snode.elementValue = typeNode +"value";
        snode.left = "2px;";
        snode.top = "2px;";
        stepNodesMap.put(id, snode); 
    }

    NavigableMap stepNodesMap;

    public NavigableMap getStepNodesMap() {
        return stepNodesMap;
    }

    public void setStepNodesMap(NavigableMap stepNodesMap) {
        this.stepNodesMap = stepNodesMap;
    }

    public void removeStepNode()
    {
        if(selecteNode!=null)
        {
            stepNodesMap.remove(selecteNode);
        }
    }


    public void onDrop(DragDropEvent dragDropEvent) 
    {
        String dragId = dragDropEvent.getDragId();
        Map<String, String> params = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();

        String left = params.get(dragId + "_left");
        String top = params.get(dragId + "_top");

        Integer idstepNode = Integer.parseInt(dragId.substring(dragId.lastIndexOf("-")+1)); 
        setSelectedElement(idstepNode);

        StepNodeSimple element = (StepNodeSimple) stepNodesMap.get(selecteNode);
        element.left = left+"px;";
        element.top = top+"px;";

    }    

}
```

Comment: [mcve] please... I suspect the cause is somewhere in code that is not here...

Comment: @Kukeltje, I've updated my question.